# Rooted Mobile Phone connected to a Wifi, it's usb tethered to a PC, how can i host a public minecraft java server in this PC? is it even possible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, android, hosting

In my wifi router, the phone's internal IP is `192.168.0.152`. I am hosting through port `6666` so i port-forwarded port `6666` to the host `192.168.0.152` in my wifi router.
[image]

In my phone, connected with `adb shell`, `ifconfig`

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:CC:2E:27:1B:90
          inet addr:192.168.0.152  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 

rndis0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:8D:91:A9:95:3C
          inet addr:192.168.42.129  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

In my PC (Ubuntu 20.04), `ifconfig`

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.146  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

Minecraft's `server.properties`, only two entries were edited, others are kept default

```
query.port=6666
server-port=6666
```

I tried the *rooted* solution provided in this answer
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342 which uses `iptables`

For my case i typed:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6666 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.146
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.42.146 --dport 6666 -j ACCEPT
```

Finally i ran the server on my PC, and i was only able to connect to it via `192.168.42.146:6666`

`{PUBLIC_IP}:6666` was unable to connect and the error are like the following
[image]

Thanks for helping!